# How might I evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx+c)}{n}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, complex-numbers

> I was trying to evaluate the sums:
>
> $$S_1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$$
>   $$S_2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx+c)}{n}$$
>
> I've found that
>   $S_1=\tan^{-1}\left(\cot\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)$, however I
>   can't seem to evaluate $S_2$. The problem is the $+c$ making it hard to simplify $\Im\left(e^{ixn}e^{ic}\right)$ with a similar technique.

To evaluate $S_1$, I said:

$$S_1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Im\left(e^{ix\cdot n}\right)}{n}=\Im\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(e^{ix}\right)^n}{n}\right)$$
Now, using the taylor series expansion of $\ln(1-a)$:
$$-\ln(1-a)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{n}$$
We have:
$$S_1=\Im\left(-\ln\left(1-e^{ix}\right)\right)=\Im\left(-\ln\left(1-\cos(x)-i\sin(x)\right)\right)$$
Converting $1-\cos(x)-i\sin(x)$ into modulus-argument form:
$$1-\cos(x)-i\sin(a)=\left(\sqrt{(1-\cos(x))^2+\sin^2(x)}\right)e^{i\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-\sin(x)}{1-\cos(x)}\right)}$$
Hence:
$$-\ln\left(1-\cos(x)-i\sin(x)\right)=-\ln\left(\sqrt{(1-\cos(x))^2+\sin^2(x)}\right)-i\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-\sin(x)}{1-\cos(x)}\right)$$
So:
$$S_1=\Im\left(-\ln\left(1-\cos(x)-i\sin(x)\right)\right)=-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-\sin(x)}{1-\cos(x)}\right)$$
Simplifying with trig identities yields:
$$S_1=\tan^{-1}\left(\cot\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Use $\sin(nx +c) =\cos(c)\sin(nx)+\sin(c)\cos(nx)$

Comment: Hmm, your Taylor series expansion for $\ln(1-a)$ actually only holds for $|a|<1$.

Comment: Also note that $\arctan(\cot(\tfrac x2)) = \tfrac{\pi-x}{2}$ for $x\neq 2k\pi$.

Comment: @amsmath Does that make my derivation invalid?

Comment: Hey Daniel. I'm not sure, to be honest.

Comment: @amsmath I think that might be after multiplying by -1 in one step?

Comment: I think that $\sum\tfrac{z^n}n$ converges for all $z\in\overline B_1(0)\setminus\{1\}$. So, it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Note that we can write

$$ \text{Im}(e^{inx}e^{ic}) =\cos(c)\text{Im}(e^{inx})+\sin(c)\text{Re}(e^{inx})$$

Comment: Thanks - I got $\cos(c)\tan^{-1}\left(\cot\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{2}\sin(c)\ln(2-2\cos(x))$

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.