# How to find the exact value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{n \pi}{4}\right)}{n^2 \cdot 2^{\frac{n}{2}}} $?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, polylogarithm

Once I met the identity

> $$
> \boxed{S_0=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{n \pi}{4}\right)}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}=1},
> $$

I first  tried to prove it by $e^{xi}=\cos x+i\sin x$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{n \pi}{4}\right)}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}} & =\Im\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^{\frac{\pi}{4} i}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^n\right]\\& =\Im\left(\frac{e^{\frac{\pi}{4} i} / \sqrt{2}}{1-e^{\frac{\pi}{4} i} / \sqrt{2}}\right)\\&=\Im\left(\frac{1+i}{1-i}\right)\\&=1
\end{aligned}
$$

and consequently $C_0=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \left(\frac{n \pi}{4}\right)}{ 2^{\frac{n}{2}}}=0 $.

---

Similarly, I try further with

$$
S_1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{n \pi}{4}\right)}{n \cdot 2^{\frac{n}{2}}}= \begin{equation}
\Im\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(e^{\frac{\pi}{4} i} / \sqrt{2}\right)^n}{n}\right]
\end{equation}
$$
Inspired by the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3163832/732917), I used the Taylor expansion of $\ln(1-t)$ for $|t|<1$.

\begin{equation}
-\ln (1-t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{n}
\end{equation}

$$
\begin{aligned}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(e^{\frac{\pi}{4} i}/ \sqrt{2}\right)^n}{n} & =-\ln \left(1-\frac{e^{\frac{\pi}{4} i}}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\ln 2+   \frac{\pi}{4} i
\end{aligned}
$$
So we got

> $$\boxed{S_1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{n \pi}{4}\right)}{n \cdot 2^{\frac{n}{2}}}=\frac{\pi}{4} } $$
> and consequently $C_1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \left(\frac{n \pi}{4}\right)}{n \cdot 2^{\frac{n}{2}}}=\frac{1}{2}\ln 2  $.

---

Both results are so nice that I then kept going with $S_2$ using the dilogarithm function $\operatorname{Li}_2$

> $$\boxed{\begin{aligned}S_2&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{n \pi}{4}\right)}{n^2 \cdot 2^{\frac{n}{2}}}= \Im\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(e^{\frac{\pi}{4} i} / \sqrt{2}\right)^n}{n^2}\right]\\& = \Im\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^n\right] =\Im \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)\end{aligned} }$$
> and consequently $C_2= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \left(\frac{n \pi}{4}\right)}{n^2 \cdot 2^{\frac{n}{2}}}=\Re \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)  $.

---

**My question**: How to find the exact value of $S_2$ or $\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right) $?

Your comments and solutions are highly appreciated.

Comment: From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4577535): $$\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)=\frac{5\pi^2}{96}-\frac{\log^2 2}8+i\left(G-\frac{\pi\log 2}8\right).$$

Comment: Thank you very much! So $S_2=G-\frac{\pi\ln 2}{8}$ and $C_2= \frac{5 \pi^2}{96}-\frac{\log ^2 2}{8}$. Glad to know that $S_2$ matches the answer I gave below.

Comment: @  
metamorphy After visiting your link, I know that it’s quite difficult to deal with $S_p=\Im  \textrm{  Li}_p(\frac{1+i}{2})$

Comment: it may or may not be helpful, but we can express your sum as the integral $$\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^1\log\left(\frac{1-e^{-i\pi/4}t/\sqrt2}{1-e^{i\pi/4}t/\sqrt2}\right)\frac{dt}{t}$$

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite  $S_2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left(n \cdot\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \cos ^n\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}{n^2} =f\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ , where

$$ f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left(nx\right) \cos ^n\left(x\right)}{n^2}
$$

Differentiating w.r.t. $x$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
f^{\prime}(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n \cos (n x) \cos ^n x-n \sin (n x) \cos ^{n-1} x \sin x}{n^2}\\
& =\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos (n x) \cos ^n x}{n}}_{g(x)}-\tan x \cdot \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (n x) \cos ^n x}{n}}_{h(x)}
\end{aligned}
$$

Grouping $g(x)$ and $h(x) $ to form a series $$
\begin{aligned}
g(x)+i h(x)& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i n x} \cos ^n x}{n} =\sum_{n=1}^n \frac{\left(e^{i x} \cos x\right)^n}{n}
\end{aligned}
$$

Using the identity for $|t|<1$,
\begin{equation}
-\ln (1-t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{n},
\end{equation}
we have
$$\begin{aligned}g(x)+ih(x)&= -\ln \left(1-e^{i x} \cos x\right)\\& =-\ln [\sin x(\sin x-i \cos x)] \\&=-\ln (\sin x)+\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right) i \end{aligned}$$
Comparing real and imaginary pars yields
$$g(x)=-\ln (\sin x)\text { and } h(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-x
$$
Putting back gives $$ f^{\prime} (x)=-\ln (\sin x)-\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right) \tan x$$

Integrating $f^{\prime} (x)$ from $0$ to $x$, we have
$$
f(x)-f(0)=-\int_0^x \ln (\sin u) d t-\int_0^x\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-u\right) \tan u d x
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x)= & -x \ln (\sin x)+\int_0^x \frac{u}{\tan u} d u+\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(\cos x)+\int_0^x u \tan u d u
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^x \frac{u}{\tan u} d x+\int_0^x u \tan u d 
= & \int_0^x \frac{u \sec ^2 u}{\tan u} d u \\
= & \int_0^x u d(\ln (\tan u)) \\
= & {[u \ln (\tan u)]_0^x \int_0^x \ln (\tan u) d u } \\
= & x \ln (\tan x)-\int_0^x \ln (\tan u) d u
\end{aligned}
$$

$$\boxed{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left(nx\right) \cos ^n\left(x\right)}{n^2}
= -x \ln (\sin x)+\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(\cos x)+ x \ln (\tan x)-\int_0^x \ln (\tan u) d u\;}$$
Now go back to our series,

> $$\begin{aligned} S_2&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{n \pi}{4}\right)}{n^2 \cdot 2^{\frac{n}{2}}}\\&=-\frac{\pi}{4} \ln \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2} \ln \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)- \int_0^{\pi/4} \ln (\tan u) d u \\&=G-\frac{\pi}{8} \ln 2\end{aligned}$$

where the last integral equals $-G$ (negative Catalan's constant G), from the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2815755/732917).

Last but not least, we may say that
$$\boxed{\Im\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right) = G-\frac{\pi}{8} \ln 2 }$$

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a comment (hoping it could be of interest to you)*

Long time ago, I worked the problem of
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^{p} \frac{\sin \left(n\frac{ \pi}{4}\right)}{n^2 \,\, 2^{\frac{n}{2}}}$$ which write (using as many $2$'s as I could)
$$2^{15}\,S_p=2^{14}\,\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-2^{6}\,\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2^4}\right)+2^4\,\Phi \left(\frac{1}{2^4},2^2,\frac{1}{2}\right)+$$
$$2^{2-4 \left\lfloor \frac{p}{2^2}\right\rfloor } \Phi
   \left(\frac{1}{2^4},2^2,\left\lfloor \frac{p}{2^2}\right\rfloor
   +1\right)-2^{13-p} \,\Phi \left(\frac{1}{2},2 ^2,p+1\right)-$$
$$2^{2^2 \left\lceil \frac{2-p}{2 ^2}\right\rceil }\Phi
   \left(\frac{1}{2^4},2^2,\left\lfloor \frac{p-2}{2^2}\right\rfloor
   +\frac{3}{2}\right)$$ where $\Phi(.)$ is the Lerch transcendent function.

What is doing  the stranger $3$ here ?

The summation converges quite fast
$$S_{10}- \left(C-\frac{1}{8} \pi  \log (2)\right)=-3.90\times 10^{-5}$$
$$S_{100}- \left(C-\frac{1}{8} \pi  \log (2)\right)=5.55\times 10^{-17}$$

Comment: Your approximation is very interesting and fast. Though the formula involves both polylogarithm function and Lerch transcendent function which are too hard to me.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Lai. As I wrote, this was for your possible curiosity (I had this in my cookbook)

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici, thank you for your recipe, haha.

Answer (score 1):

**Dilogarithm Function**

Using the [identity 25.12.3](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12#ii), we have $$
Li_2(1-z)+Li_2\left(1-z^{-1}\right)=-\frac{1}{2} \ln ^2(z)
$$
Putting $z=\frac{1+i}{2}$ into it yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
& L_2\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)+L_2(-i)=-\frac{1}{2} \ln ^2\left(\frac{1-i}{2}\right) \\
\Rightarrow \quad  & L_2\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)-\frac{\pi^2}{48}-i G=\frac{\pi^2}{32}-\frac{\ln ^2 2}{8}-\frac{\pi}{8} i \ln 2 \\
\Rightarrow \quad & L_2\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)=\frac{5 \pi^2}{96}-\frac{\ln ^2 2}{8}+\left(G-\frac{\pi}{8} \ln 2\right) i
\end{aligned}
$$
where $G$ is the Catalan’s constant.
Hence
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{n \pi}{4}\right)}{n^2 \cdot 2^{\frac{n}{2}}} =G-\frac{\pi}{8} \ln 2$$

As a bonus,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \left(\frac{n \pi}{4}\right)}{n^2 \cdot 2^{\frac{n}{2}}}=\frac{5 \pi^2}{96}-\frac{\ln ^2 2}{8}$$

Comment: Would Mr downvoter please give suggestions for me to improve my solution?